# How to do a plane with hole using a simple 3d software

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d

I need a simple 3d software (or a solution inside Unity 3d) to makes hole on a plane. 
I don't need nothing complicated, because i have no knowledge  of 3d software.

Can you suggest me a Unity asset or the simplest 3d software to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use Blender. Add new object by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and choose from mesh menu the "plane"

[image]

In Blender with default settings, you select things with the right mouse button.
Now if wanted you can scale the object by pressing S and activate the new scale by pressing Left mouse buttons. Apply the scale (to avoid future problems by pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and select from the list "scale"

[image]

We are going to add the object by using the Boolean operation in this example. Select again new object from the "<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>" menu. I use in my example the cylinder.

[image]

Select the plane with right click and go to the modifiers tab which can be identified with the wrench icon in the right panel.

[image]

Click "add the modifier" and select from the list "boolean".

Now you select from the "object" list, the object that is named "cylinder" and click it.

[image]

Select from the "operation" drop menu" difference.

[image]

If you want to, you can move the cylinder in a place where you like it more with the colored arrows in 3d-view. Or you can scale it with <kbd>S</kbd> key.

Click "apply" in the modifier settings.

You can now select the cylinder with right click and press "delete" to remove it. Now you can save or export your object from the file menu.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not an Unity game programmer, but I can read that Unity imports Sketchup files (*.SKP) and files in OBJ format + many more. I also can read that Unity hasn't own 3D modeller included so extra software is needed.

The easiest 3D app to start with is SketchUP. That's my opinion. Here's a screenshot from SketchUP:

[image]

There's a rectangular piece of a plane, a circle drawn onto it, another circle which is selected and a hole. One second earlier the hole was also a selected circle. Then I pressed DEL. The whole job after the program had started and showed an empty workspace took less than 10 seconds.

SketchUP has a free version for simple works and an enormous battery of downloadable shapes and functional extensions  from other user's. After working some tutorials with it you probably understand 3D enough to be able to do this and much more complex jobs. Then you'll laugh for this case.

NOT ASKED: Unity is designed to take 3D material from pro level 3D programs such as Maya or Blender. A serious game developer should apply it to take all benefit of the available integration.Do not forget that games rely much on moving and shape altering objects that obey physics. Unfortunately it's not beginner's job and it's not available in simple 3D software such as SketchUP.

Comment: it does not really matter how you author your assets, its just that sketchup is not meant for animation and other standard  concepts found in document content creation applications. For same reason you would avoid using CAD software for this purpose. Hoewer its not wrong just wasteful.